# In my pivot table, how to I get one of my Column headings to be equal to the sum of that row?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot-table

Im working on an MS-Access project using SQL. I have a query using the following SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Milestone.Weight) AS SumOfWeight
SELECT Milestone.[Expected Date]
FROM Studys LEFT JOIN Milestone ON Studys.[Primary Key] = Milestone.[Study ID]
GROUP BY Milestone.[Expected Date]
ORDER BY Milestone.[Expected Date]
PIVOT Studys.[Assigned User];
```

Which works as intended and creates the following results

[image]
I simply want an extra Column that is the sum of that row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a query based of this query selecting all of the column headings as well as an expression equal to the sum of all the column headings:

```
  (colm1+ colm2 +colm3) as sum
```